# Dynamically get count of customers by year

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I have data like below [image]

and would like to show it in a Power BI visual like this.

[image]

I am aware of creating pivoting and unpivoting the data, But I am looking of the count of customers in few buckets (lets say gap of 5 years) and it should be dynamic (I know this can be achieved using M language, but I am not able to wrap my head around it) Please could someone provide insights about this.

Comment: The expected result in your question is inconsistent, since you're altering between ranges of 6 and 4 years.

Comment: Apologies for the inconsistent data showed in my example but you have understood my question correctly...so would you mind removing the down arrow for this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a calculated colum:

```
5 Year Bin =
FLOOR ( DIVIDE ( data[Year], 5 ), 1 ) * 5 & "-"
    & FLOOR ( DIVIDE ( data[Year], 5 ), 1 ) * 5 + 4
```

This looks like:

| Year | 5 Year Bin |
| --- | --- |
| 1910 | 1910-1914 |
| 1911 | 1910-1914 |
| 1912 | 1910-1914 |
| 1913 | 1910-1914 |
| 1915 | 1915-1919 |
| 1916 | 1915-1919 |
| 1917 | 1915-1919 |
| 1918 | 1915-1919 |
| 1919 | 1915-1919 |
| 1920 | 1920-1924 |
| 1921 | 1920-1924 |
| 1922 | 1920-1924 |
| 1923 | 1920-1924 |
| 1924 | 1920-1924 |
| 1925 | 1925-1929 |
| 1926 | 1925-1929 |
| 1927 | 1925-1929 |
| 1928 | 1925-1929 |
| 1929 | 1925-1929 |
| 1930 | 1930-1934 |
| 1931 | 1930-1934 |

To get the "5 Years Bin" to the columns add a matrix visualisation and configure it to show "5 Years Bin" in the columns and CountOfCustomers as values:

[image: Create matrix visualisation]

The result looks like this:

| 1910-1914 | 1915-1919 | 1920-1924 | 1925-1929 | 1930-1934 | **Total** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 10 | 16 | 41 | 23 | **98** |

Answer (score 0):

You can use binned groups to achieve this behaviour:

In Power BI, right click on Year column and click "New group":

[image: Create group]

Then configure your binned group:

[image: Configure binned group]

To get the Years to the columns add a matrix visualisation and configure it to show "Year (bins)" in the columns and CountOfCustomers as values:

[image: Configure matrix]

The result looks like this:

| 1910 | 1915 | 1920 | 1925 | 1930 | **Total** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 10 | 16 | 41 | 23 | **98** |

Comment: Thank you Andreas...But I wanted the years to be a range (meaning...1910-1915,1916-1920...dynamically)...is there any way this can be achieved?

Comment: Thank you. But the point is to show years as a "Range" of customers for that particular years. In this case, there are chances that the any one can misunderstand that the count for the year 1910 as 8 but it is the count for the years between 1910-1915. Hope you go it.

Comment: @balaji They in fact are a range of 5 yrs, there is just no possibility to name the columns like you want, so 1910 means 1910-1914, 1915 means 1915-1919 and so on. I used the data you provided, so if you look at it you will recognize that for example the sum of the years between 1920 and 1924 is exactly 16. 
The expected result in your question is inconsistent, since you're altering between ranges of 6 and 4 years. In my opinion my solution provides the correct results per 5 year range.

Comment: @balaji I created an alternative answer which addresses your concerns since both are valid in my opinon.